# Only the Tomcat v8.0 is not shown in Eclipse while defining a new server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

when I try to add a new server in Eclipse v3.8, all Apache Tomcat versions are listed in the selecting server options but the v8.0:

[image]

I checked that **JST Server Adapters** and **JST Server Adapters Extensions** are already installed.

[image]

I need Apache Tomcat v8.0, what should I do?

PS: I use Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Crazy Ninja suggests, I updated **JST Server Adapters** and **JST Server Adapters Extensions** from Mars update site: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/

After that, Tomcat v8.0 is available as an option while defining a new server without upgrading the Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 8.0 is available after Eclipse Luna (4.4) version. You might want to upgrade your eclipse IDE